# Sign in to google apps account without redirect to external login?

Tags: gmail, google-apps, saml, google-apps-for-education

I'm admin of google apps for education console. How can i create a user that login directly from gmail page without redirecting to the external page configured to the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: I flagged this to be moved to Server Fault because, frankly, I have no idea where it's on-topic.

Comment: @CodingWithClass Sorry, how can i move it?

Comment: You have to wait for a reviewer to accept the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your question about how to configure "SSO" login for some users and non-SSO login for other users?  If so, you can only configure that by location today, you cannot configure it by user.  SSO is either on for everyone or off for everyone unless it is by location (i.e. in the office you use SSO but at home you use your Google account to login).

The only exception to this is "Super Admin" accounts which do not use SSO to login.

Comment: Exactly what i want. I'm super admin, so i can login non-SSO. That explain everything.